# Upload files with multiple inputs

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a form where i want to upload files with multiple inputs.My form looks like:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="tax" />
    <input type="file" name="ta" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

I do not know how to process this form..

Answer (score 0):

You form doesn't work until you don't include 'enctype="multipart/form-data"', because it is necessary to use input type file.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="tax" />
    <input type="file" name="ta" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Now browse the file and submit the form. You will get all file data inside $_FILES. so to check what you get inside the file data, you can use :

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_FILES)
```

Comment: @AayushGarg, if my answer resolved your issue, then accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you have gone through the tutorials before, however below is the code which will help you to process it.

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="tax" />
    <input type="file" name="ta" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

If you upload the file, you can get the files from,

`$_FILES` global array, i.e. $_FILES['tax'] and $_FILES['ta'].

More info can be found on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="tax" />
    <input type="file" name="ta" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<?php
    //print_r($_POST);
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name       = $_FILES['tax']['name'];
        $name1       = $_FILES['ta']['name'];
        $temp_name  = $_FILES['tax']['tmp_name']; 
        $temp_name1  = $_FILES['ta']['tmp_name']; 
        var_dump($_FILES);
        if(isset($name)){
            if(!empty($name)){ 
            var_dump($_FILES);     
                $location = 'images/'.$name;      
                if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location)){
                    echo 'File uploaded successfully';

                }
            }       
        }  else {
            echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
        }
        if(isset($name1)){
            if(!empty($name1)){ 
            var_dump($_FILES);     
                $location = 'images/'.$name1;      
                if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name1, $location)){
                    echo 'File uploaded successfully';

                }
            }       
        }  else {
            echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
        }
    }

    ?>
```